# With the latest IDEA version update 2023.2, the karate run via karate plugin hangs even though all the scenarios have completed execution

Tags: karate

With the latest IDEA version update 2023.2, the karate run via the karate plugin hangs even though all the scenarios have completed execution
Because of this issue, it is not possible to generate the report via the plugin run

karate plugin version - 1.7.6.353-232

[image]

Comment: have responded on the issue you raised on github itself